# Undo actions done prior to netbeans restart

Tags: java, plugins, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Is there any way to enable undo for actions done, prior to Netbeans restart, after the netbeans is restarted ?

Any plugin support for this would also do fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 'Local History' NetBeans plugin (this plugin is installed by default). As you can see on screenshot the Undo and Redo buttons are inactive but I can see file's changes.[image]